# How to store SQL query result in a variable using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, qsqlquery

I want to store the first query result in a variable and use the first query result as a value in the second query.

Currently the second query works on its own. I am just having difficulties getting the first one to work.

```
$var = array();$idorigin = $conn->prepare("SELECT id_stop FROM stops WHERE
stopname = '$value1'");
$idorigin->execute()
$var[] = $idorigin['id_Stop'];
echo $var;

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id_stop, scheduletime FROM schedule 
WHERE scheduletime >= '$time' AND id_stop = '8'
LIMIT 6;");


$stmt->execute();
echo $stmt;
```

Comment: Are you really able to echo an array and object?

Comment: *Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers*

Comment: no the echo for the fist part did now work, only the second query with the echo worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this for your first statement :

```
$req = $conn->prepare("SELECT id_stop FROM stops WHERE stopname = :value");
$req->execute(array('value' => $value1));
$result = $req->fetchAll();
$req->closeCursor();
var_dump($result);
```

1. First you prepare your query
2. Execute it with the corresponding parameters
3. [Fetch all](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) records from the DB and store the result in any variable (here $result)
4. [Close connection with server](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php), which allows to run other queries after
5. Display the content of your variable with [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried that and it says Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::execute() in C:\wamp64\www\Schedule.php on line 132 - which is the $conn->execute(array(  'value' => $value1));

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake! Made an edit and now should work.. just make sure $conn is a valid pdo object

Comment: @GabrielBourgault Fix your `execute()` statement, it should be `$req->execute(array(':value' => $value1));`

Comment: It works now but the var_dump displays the results : C:\wamp64\www\Schedule.php:136:
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id_stop' => string '21' (length=2)
      0 => string '21' (length=2) on the website
and when used in the following query it throws an error : Notice: Array to string conversion

Comment: @camnesia yes that is the purpose of [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

Comment: I tried : $req = $conn->prepare("SELECT id_stop FROM stops WHERE stopname = :value");
$req->execute(array(
        'value' => $value1));
$result2 = $req->fetchAll();
$req->closeCursor();
    
$origin = serialize($result2);
echo $origin;
but the result is  = a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:7:"id_stop";s:2:"21";i:0;s:2:"21";}}
rather than the single id_stop value = "21"

Comment: @camnesia You seem to be confusing single variables with arrays. `fetchAll()` returns an array. You seem to want to extract a single value, you can't just serialize it. Could you provide an example of your database?

Comment: My Table has 2 columns : id_stop and stopname
when the user inputs a stopname on the website i want to query that name from the database and get the matching id_stop and store that value.
I want to be able to use that single value, that is a numeric value between 1-25 from id_stop, in the second query.

Comment: I think i need to make my question more specific, since your answer did what i asked for , I just didn't ask the right thing. Thank you very much :)